# How to create a custom import in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, import, dataflow

We need to create a custom data import in Magento 2. In Magento 1 we used to use the Dataflow model to implement our custom imports.

In Magento 2 there are no 'advanced profiles' but an 'Import' section. Does anyone know if it's possible to add new custom entities to that import section? Any examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom import with Magento 2.

You can based on the `CatalogImportExport` or `CustomerImportExport` Magento module which is based on the `ImportExport` Magento module  as a reference.

**Basic step :**

- Create your `CustomImportExport` Module
- Add an `import.xml` configuration file

  - Add your entity model and behavior
  - Add your entity type if needed
  - Add the relatedInxexer to refresh after import
- Implement your import model with your logic

**Code Examples:**

**import.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="catalog_product" label="Products" model="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
    <entityType entity="catalog_product" name="simple" model="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\Type\Simple" />
    <entityType entity="catalog_product" name="virtual" model="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\Type\Virtual" />
    <relatedIndexer entity="catalog_product" name="catalog_product_price" />
    <relatedIndexer entity="catalog_product" name="catalogsearch_fulltext" />
    <relatedIndexer entity="catalog_product" name="catalog_product_flat" />
</config>
```

**Behavior module**

```
Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic
```

**Product Import model example :**

```
Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product
```

Comment: Any idea how to import export categories in csv same as product via backend?

Comment: I have added Entity Type "catalog_category" in export.xml and displaying in Entity Type drop down. But issue in Vendor\CategoryImportExport\Model\Export\Category.php files not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_import">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity Id" identity="true" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Product Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="duration" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Duration"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="CUSTOM_IMPORT_ID_PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

[image]

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**import.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="custom_import" label="Custom Import" model="VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import\CustomImport" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Files/Sample**

**custom_import.csv**

```
entity_id,name,duration
,"Name 1",90
2,"Name 3",120
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\SampleFileProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="samples" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_import" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_CustomDataImport</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Model/Import**

**CustomImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data as ImportHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data;

/**
 * Class Courses
 */
class CustomImport extends AbstractEntity
{
    const ENTITY_CODE = 'custom_import';
    const TABLE = 'custom_import';
    const ENTITY_ID_COLUMN = 'entity_id';

    /**
     * If we should check column names
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;

    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;

    /**
     * Permanent entity columns.
     */
    protected $_permanentAttributes = [
        'entity_id',
    ];

    /**
     * Valid column names
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
        'entity_id',
        'name',
        'duration',
    ];

    /**
     * @var AdapterInterface
     */
    protected $connection;

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * Courses constructor.
     *
     * @param JsonHelper $jsonHelper
     * @param ImportHelper $importExportData
     * @param Data $importData
     * @param ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param Helper $resourceHelper
     * @param ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
     */
    public function __construct(
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper,
        ImportHelper $importExportData,
        Data $importData,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        Helper $resourceHelper,
        ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
        $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
        $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection(ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
        $this->initMessageTemplates();
    }

    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return static::ENTITY_CODE;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValidColumnNames(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }

    /**
     * Row validation
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum): bool
    {
        $name = $rowData['name'] ?? '';
        $duration = (int) $rowData['duration'] ?? 0;

        if (!$name) {
            $this->addRowError('NameIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (!$duration) {
            $this->addRowError('DurationIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
            return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
        }

        $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;

        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }

    /**
     * Init Error Messages
     */
    private function initMessageTemplates()
    {
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'NameIsRequired',
            __('The name cannot be empty.')
        );
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'DurationIsRequired',
            __('Duration should be greater than 0.')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Import data
     *
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _importData(): bool
    {
        switch ($this->getBehavior()) {
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE:
                $this->deleteEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntity(): bool
    {
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                $this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum);

                if (!$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum)) {
                    $rowId = $rowData[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                    $rows[] = $rowId;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($rows) {
            return $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows));
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Save and replace entities
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function saveAndReplaceEntity()
    {
        $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            $entityList = [];

            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $row) {
                if (!$this->validateRow($row, $rowNum)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);

                    continue;
                }

                $rowId = $row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                $rows[] = $rowId;
                $columnValues = [];

                foreach ($this->getAvailableColumns() as $columnKey) {
                    $columnValues[$columnKey] = $row[$columnKey];
                }

                $entityList[$rowId][] = $columnValues;
                $this->countItemsCreated += (int) !isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
                $this->countItemsUpdated += (int) isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
            }
            if (Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE === $behavior) {
                if ($rows && $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows))) {
                    $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
                }
            } elseif (Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND === $behavior) {
                $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save entities
     *
     * @param array $entityData
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData): bool
    {
        if ($entityData) {
            $tableName = $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE);
            $rows = [];

            foreach ($entityData as $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $rows[] = $row;
                }
            }

            if ($rows) {
                $this->connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $rows, $this->getAvailableColumns());

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @param array $entityIds
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntityFinish(array $entityIds): bool
    {
        if ($entityIds) {
            try {
                $this->countItemsDeleted += $this->connection->delete(
                    $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE),
                    $this->connection->quoteInto(static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN . ' IN (?)', $entityIds)
                );

                return true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAvailableColumns(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }
}
```