# What is the best and fastest way to create products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, import

I am developing a connector between Magento 2 and an ERP system. And I have to import 1000s of products from ERP to magento. And Update them using cron.

So I want to know what is the best way to bulk import products. And how they can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

There's a Magento 2 version of FastSimpleImport:

https://github.com/firegento/FireGento_FastSimpleImport2

It allows you to programmatically access Magento\ImportExport module and will be quite fast (50-100 products per second).

Comment: based on standard Magento import (CSV)
but can import via Data array

very fast

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use dirty custom scripts, it's better to follow extensions creation guide and extend Magento 2 Import on proper way, this will help you build solid integration with 3th party platforms. Here is useful links to get started with extend Magento 2 import:

- [Magento 2 Import Export In Custom Module Development](https://www.forgeonline.co.nz/magento-2-import-export-module-development/)
- [import custom csv to custom table- magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114525/import-custom-csv-to-custom-table-magento-2)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/169495/2282
- Stable open source implementation of PIM connector - https://github.com/Agence-DnD/PIMGento-2