# Admin csv uploader

Tags: magento2, admin, csv

I have created a empty admin page, it appears in the side bar and redirect to the correct place although I don't have a controller working.
In this page I need a csv uploader then I need to send and email to every email in the csv with the info associated to it, but my problem is that I don't know how to put a uploader in the page, i've searched and found some things with the system xml but I can't get any to work.
Any help? A step by step with the files I need to create/edit would be great if possible I'm net to magento so some things get a bit confusing.

Thanks :D

Comment: For this You'll have to create one simple module or you can do in any existing module's system.xml file if you know the structure, but if you are new to Magento, please create a new module and refer the system.xml file as per below link which has also answered by me previously.  
`https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279879/magento-2-how-to-upload-csv-in-admin-and-update-data-in-custom-admin-grid-table`

Comment: @DineshRajput ye I already have a module and it shows just a title, I have a system.xml too. But how do I make de uploader appear in the backoffice? What do I load in the .phtml file? and after that to read the upload it's the event.xml right?
Thanks

Comment: Okay, I have the form and the action is Tracking/Upload/Post then I have app/code/Custom/Tracking/Controller/Adminhtml/Upload/Post.php, but it does not seem to go to the controller, what's needed?

Comment: to call your admin controller,you'll have to create admin routes.xml in add/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml